# I am passing a list from one class to another but i am getting error saying "Consumer can not converted to list Integer"

Tags: java

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();

Consumer consumer = new Consumer(new Consumer(list));
```

---

```
public class Consumer extends Thread{

    List<Integer> list;

    public Consumer(List<Integer> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you passing two ``new Consumer`` to the variable? try this ``Consumer consumer = new Consumer(list)``.

Comment: "Consumer consumer = new Consumer(new Consumer(list));" Are you absolutely sure this is your code?

Comment: :I that was very stupid of me. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Replace `Consumer consumer = new Consumer(new Consumer(list));`
  by

`Consumer consumer = new Consumer(list);`

Answer (score 0):

Because your constructor is of type `public Consumer(List<Integer> list)`

but you trying to pass `new Consumer(list)` which is produce the conflict.

Solution is:

```
Consumer consumer = new Consumer(list);
```

instead

```
Consumer consumer = new Consumer(new Consumer(list));
```

Answer (score 0):

Consumer object constructor is accepting List as argument, but you are passing Consumer object as parameter.

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();

Consumer consumer = new Consumer(list); // Changed here


public class Consumer extends Thread{

    List<Integer> list;

    public Consumer(List<Integer> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }
}
```